# Script fails to submit to SGE, immediately to Eqw, no stdout/stderr

Tags: nfs, hpc, sungridengine

I am submitting some very simple scripts many times (~103) to SGE all with the same working directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $MYVAR
```

When run one by one, they all execute successfully. When I have reached about ~30 submitted jobs, a few of them fail to submit and go immediately to `Eqw` state. When I inspect the qstatus with `qstat -j $jobid -explain E`, the status is as follows.

```
sge_o_shell:                 /bin/bash
sge_o_workdir:               /home/myname/some/common/path
sge_o_host:                  hostly
notify:                      FALSE
job_name:                    scriptXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.sh
jobshare:                    0
shell_list:                  NONE:/bin/bash
env_list:                    
mail_list                    myname@hostly.example.com
error reason    1:           12/07/2016 11:14:58 [123456:123456]: error: can't chdir to /home/myname/some/common
scheduling info:             Job is in error state
```

I am using an NFS-mounted home directory as the common working directory for SGE. The directory exists and has files in it already. It doesn't mention the normal `can't chdir to $PATH; file or directory does not exist` and simply says it can't chdir to a parental directory. Is this most likely an NFS issue?

Comment: How many jobs per node are you seeing when the failure occurs?

Comment: Are all of them running in the same host?

Comment: @alvaro, I tried both a single host and multiple nodes and it was *mildly* reproducible with a single host. Steve, it was around 15+/- jobs per node when I first encountered the issue. I have revised this question to also include the NFS tag.